# Angular js $q Service "all" method is ignored when promise is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I'm using the `$q` service to wait for a promise to be returned, however the service that defines the promise is being hit after the directive with the `$q` service. So when the `$q` service is called, the promise is `undefined`.

In the directive (being hit first)

```
this.qService.all([this.summaryVm.positionsServicePromise]).then((result: Array<any>) => {...}
```

In the Service (being hit second)

```
this.summaryVm = vm;
var positionServicePromise = this.$http.get(this.url);
this.summaryVm.positionsServicePromise = positionServicePromise;
```

I need the `$http.get()` to be called in the `PositionsService`, and it seems that the `$q` service ignores the all `.then` if the promise is `undefined`. Is there a way to temporarily define the promise where the all `.then` waits for the promise to update?

Comment: can you share more of your code to get the context?

Answer (score 0):

Inject the Service into the directive and then the service will be hit first.